# How to save a resource from an executable jar file to local drive?

Tags: java, jar, save, resources, local

I wonder if there is a way to extract a resource file packaged in an executable jar file and save it to a local drive, so when a user downloads my jar file and double clicks on it, it will first save one file from the resource to his C: drive, then run my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get an `InputStream` to the contents of that resource, and write it to (say) the temp directory. In your `main()` method just do this before you do execute the main part of your program.

Comment: How to write an InputStream to a file called "abc.xyz" ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write that logic into your program.  Executing a `JAR` file is just going to run the main class.  If the first thing the `main` method in that class does is to copy the file to a location on disk, it seems like this would meet your requirements.

Here is the [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) on copying a file in Java.

Comment: Is that copyTo() method referenced only in Java7/OpenJDK ? And will it copy from a resource contained *within* a .jar file ?